# How to use the `every` and the `any` Groovy methods?

Tags: groovy

I'm trying to understand how both methods [every and any](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/groovy/groovy_any_every.htm) are working. I thought I had it but no. Here my example:

```
assert (["Test", "Case", "Way"].findAll {it ==~ /^r[a-z0-9]*/}.isEmpty()) == true
assert (["Test", "Case", "Way"].findAll {it ==~ /^r[a-z0-9]*/}.every { it.startsWith("intTest") }) == true
```

I'm always getting here true although none of the array elements is matching the pattern so none of them can start with "intTest".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are no elements in your list.

Logically `every` returns true if the list is empty (as every element in the collection -- all 0 of them -- passes the test)

```
assert [].every { it == 1 } == true
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer @tim-yates.

Comment: However I would consider it as another Groovy's _pitfall_, rather then something _logical_ ;-) because as there are *no* elements in the list, none of them passes the test. Anyway, +1

Comment: @Niko if it answers your question, please accept this answer.

Comment: So you can switch it around to use `any`: `assert (["Test", "Case", "Way"].findAll {it ==~ /^r[a-z0-9]*/}.any { !it.startsWith("intTest") }) == false`

Comment: @tim_yates I know, I've checked the implementation, so I know it's expected to work this way... I only meant it can be surprising at first.

Comment: @EelLee Agreed :-)